# Visual studio 2012 hangs frequently

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, freeze

Visual studio 2012 hangs frequently. Every time I am trying to close it through TaskManager and when opening the solution, visual studio will stay for 1 to 2 mins then hangs.

Restarted my system.
Restarted Visual studio 10 times.
Closing all the files in Visual studio when restarting the solution.

My observation : This is happening after installing Json.net through nugetpackagemanager and adding reference to Newtonsoft.JSon .

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Download VS 2013, its awesome with GITHUB Integration and Many productive tools.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot do that as organization wide we are using 2012.

I have undone the changes in the current branch. It is not hanging now.